# Cant get RDP to work with a 2wire router

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I've got a 2wire router for uverse and I haven't been able to connect via RDP through this router.  Here are the steps I've followed

- Setup a windows 7 box with RDP, patched and up to date
- Disabled the firewall temporarily on the windows 7 box
- Placed server in DMZ (2wire calls it DMZPlus or something)
- Attempted to RDP into the server.

It connects, authenticates (it will even alert me if the auth is invalid) and attempts to bring up the desktop but fails and says something along the lines of "encryption has failed, disconnecting".  I'll update the question when I'm able to see the exact message again.

- Attempted to RDP into the server from another PC on the LAN, successful

So now I'm unable to completely connect to the RDP box remotely.  I'll update the question with more precise settings and error messages when I get back to the server later on, but for now I'm looking for suggestions as to what to try.

Additional info:

The server and client are both windows 7 running the latest version of RDP and are fully patched.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the RDP "Server Authentication" setting on the client RDP connection settings.  Are they same on the machine that doesn't work, and the machine that does work?  I'm thinking the client that doesn't work is set to "Do not connect", when maybe it should be on "Warn Me"
[image: RDP Config]

Comment: Nah its set to warn me, and it does warn